# Headless bolts blocking ignition swap on '16 CBR

Tags: motorcycle, ignition-switch, theft-prevention

Is there a good way to remove headless bolts?

My lock cylinder was ruined from an attempted theft over a year ago. I got a replacement from the same model and my self-repair is being blocked by these two headless bolts under the ignition.

Guides aren't easily available because of the sensitive nature of replacing the ignition. The ones I can find say to cut a notch in the bolt (and the housing) to get traction with a screwdriver.

While I could do this, I am concerned it would harm the value of the bike. I have the original keys and documentation that I am the owner. I'm considering just taking it to a shop or dealership to keep everything on record.

Comment: Those are tamper proof bolts, once removed they should be replaced with new ones, they have a head on them that breaks off when tightening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always managed to use a tapered punch to turn them - these were customers cars so no damage allowed...

Once they started turning a pair of needle nose pliers worked.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I was thinking. Can this be done without taking the assembly off the bike?